# Vlookup using excel for range data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, index-match

I have two excel files, I want to perform vlookup and find difference of costs using  excel.

My files look like this

source_data.xlsx contains contains distance covered and their price, example distance range from 1 to 100 should be charged 4800 and distance range from 101 to 120 should be charged 5100.

```
DISTANCE     COST    
1-100        4800
101-120      5100    
121-140      5500    
141-160      5900    
161-180      6200    
181-200      6600    
210-220      6900   
221-240      7200
```

Analysis.xlsx

```
loading_station  distance_travel     total_cost    status    
PUGU                  40                4000       PAID        
PUGU                  80                3200       PAID    
MOROGORO              50                5000       PAID    
MOROGORO              220               30400      PAID    
DODOMA                150               5100       PAID   
KIGOMA                90                2345       PAID   
DODOMA                230               6000       PAID    
DODOMA                180               16500      PAID    
KIGOMA                32                3000       PAID    
DODOMA                45                6000       PAID   
DODOMA                65                5000       PAID    
KIGOMA                77                1000       PAID    
KIGOMA                90                4000       PAID
```

Actual Cost for distance is given in source_data.xlsx, I want to check cost in Analysis.xlsx if it correspond to Actual value, I want to detect underpayment and overpayment.

Desired Output should be like this, with two column added, source_cost which is taken from source_xlsx by using vlookup and difference which is difference between total_cost and source_cost

```
loading_station distance_travel total_cost  status  source_cost Difference    
PUGU               40                4000     PAID     4800        -800    
PUGU               80                3200     PAID     4800        -1600    
MOROGORO           50                5000     PAID     4800         200    
MOROGORO           220               30400    PAID     6900         23500    
DODOMA             150               5100     PAID     5900         -800    
KIGOMA             90                2345     PAID     4800         -2455   
DODOMA             230               6000     PAID     7200         -1200   
DODOMA             180               16500    PAID     6200          10300
KIGOMA             32                3000     PAID     4800          -1800
DODOMA             45                6000     PAID     4800           1200 
DODOMA             65                5000     PAID     4800           200   
KIGOMA             77                1000     PAID     4800           -3800  
KIGOMA             90                4000     PAID     4800           -800
```

Comment: You have forgotten to include your own attempt for debugging purposes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Vlookup(B40,$A$2:$B$8,2,1)
```

This assumes the distance/cost is in the table A2:B8, and the first cost to be found based on distance given is in B40.

But why do you get a result of 4000 for a distance of 40, when your table of distance/cost (analysis) shows anything 1 to 100 is 4800?